# Need some help understanding one step in this proof of homeomorphism $\Omega (C(X)) \cong X$

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $\Omega (C(X))$ the space of characters on $C(X)$. I am showing that the map $x \mapsto e_x$ where $e_x$ is evaluation at $x$ is surjective (I already showed it's injective). But I just can't understand one step in the proof I am reading. Let me give the proof here:

Let $\tau \in \Omega (C(X))$ be a character. Then $K = \operatorname{ker}{\tau}$ is a maximal ideal in $C(X)$ and therefore proper and closed. Using Urysohn's lemma it is easy to see that $K$ separates points. Since $K$ is proper and contains $1$ it cannot vanish nowhere hence there must exist $x \in X$ such that for all $f \in K$ we have that $f(x) = 0$.

So far so good. Now here comes the step I don't understand:

Hence $(f-\tau(f))(x) = 0$ so $f(x) = \tau(f) \color{red}{\text{ for all }}$ $f\in C(X)$.

It is clear to me that if $f \in K$ then $\tau(f) = 0$ and by how $x$ was chosen also $f(x) = 0$ and therefore the above claim holds for all $f \in K$. But why does  it hold for all $f \in C(X)$?

Comment: Note that $f - \tau(f)\cdot \mathbb{1} \in K$, since $\tau(f-\tau(f)\cdot\mathbb{1}) = \tau(f) - \tau(f)\cdot \tau(\mathbb{1}) = \tau(f) - \tau(f) = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you! So much. I understand it now.

Comment: @DanielFischer But isn't this a contradiction? This is saying that $K = C(X)$! But $K$ is a maximal ideal and therefore proper. What am I missing?

Comment: No, it says $C(X) = K + \mathbb{C}\cdot \mathbb{1}$, and in particular, for all $f\in C(X)$, we have $f - \tau(f)\cdot \mathbb{1}\in K$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am now doubtful that from $\tau(x)=0$ you can deduce $x=0$. Is this really true?

Comment: @DanielFischer The other thing I don't understand is: why, if for all $f$ we have $f - \tau(f) = 0$ then why did we have to construct an $x$ such that all $f$ in the kernel are zero at $x$?

Comment: No, from $\tau(x) = 0$ you cannot conclude $x = 0$. Just that $x$ is in the kernel of $\tau$. We don't have $f-\tau(f) = 0$, we have $\tau(f-\tau(f)\cdot\mathbb{1}) = 0$. Now you have deduced that there is an $x_0\in X$ such that $(\forall g\in\ker\tau)(g(x_0) = 0)$. Since for all $f\in C(X)$ we have $f-\tau(f)\cdot\mathbb{1}\in\ker\tau$, it follows that $0 = f(x_0) - \tau(f)\cdot \mathbb{1}(x_0) = f(x_0) - \tau(f)\cdot 1 = f(x_0)-\tau(f)$ for all $f$, that is, $\tau(f) = f(x_0)$ for all $f$, i.e. $\tau = e_{x_0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $0=e_{x}(f)=\tau(f)$ $\forall f\in K$

So, $e_{x}$ and $\tau$ are two linear functionals that are equals in the hyperplane $K$. Also, $e_{x}(1)=\tau(1)=1$ since $\tau$ is multiplicative. Then, $e_{x}=\tau$

Comment: Why does it follow that if they are equal on $K$ and equal on $1$ that they are equal everywhere?

Comment: Because $K$ and $\{1\}$ are a spanning set? But the space is infinite dimensional so there can't be a spanning set.

Comment: @student There are spanning sets also in infinite-dimensional spaces (the entire space is always a spanning set, for example), just no finite spanning sets. But $K$ is a subspace of codimension $1$, so it is infinite (unless $X$ has only one point).

Comment: So there are two ways of continuing the argument in the question: this here in the answer and yours in the comment?

Comment: At least two, @student. I expect that one could think up further methods, but these are the most usual arguments.

Comment: @DanielFischer Are all maximal ideals in a Banach algebra of codimension one?

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, this one I can answer in my situation: I can use the rank nullity theorem on my character: then dimension of kernel plus one give dimension of the whole space. So codimension of the kernel is one.

Comment: @student In the infinite-dimensional case, the rank-nullity theorem doesn't suffice for that, but if $M$ is a maximal ideal in the complex Banach algebra $B$, then $B/M$ is a Banach algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ which is a field. Thus by Gelfand-Mazur, $B/M \cong \mathbb{C}$, so is one-dimensional.